# How to write to file with Rollup.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, rollupjs

I'm currently competing in MIT Battlecode 2019 (https://github.com/battlecode/battlecode19). They are using rollup, which as far as I understand disables the "require" keyword and only allows "import". I try to do

```
import fs from 'fs';
```

It finds 'fs' but since 'fs' has 'require' in its own dependencies it fails with 'ReferenceError: require is not defined'. Is it impossible to write to a file?

Comment: what format are you trying to obtain for the final output file ? Also I believe you have to use `export fs from 'fs'` instead of `import fs from 'fs' `. The module is relative to your path but you can use the [rollup-plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve). And since the modules you are using are in CommonJS format you will also have to use the [rollup-plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs). I would recommend you read the [FAQ](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#faqs).

Answer (score -1):

Try changing config as below: More details can be found at this [link](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/issues/239).

```
plugins: [
        // commonjs before bultins      
        commonjs(), // import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
        builtins(), //  import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins';
]
```

Comment: The problem is I do not have access to the configuration file as they are hosting the server. I am limited to how they set it up - Actually I search their repo and do not find a config file at all!

Comment: You might need to use `external: ['fs']` in config file again. Sorry mate, I couldn't help you.

Comment: @kRiZ that still doesn't work for me I've even added `rollup-plugin-node-globals`do you perhaps have a working example?

Comment: @FarajiAnderson I do not have any working examples now. You can follow the above-mentioned thread to get more info.